# How to query for an entity that contains a specific related entity, with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and have the following entities ...

```
class Foo
{
  public int FooId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
};

class Bar
{
  public int BarId { get; set; }
  public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
};
```

I'm using the repository pattern and `Foo` is a top level entity and `Bar` is only really available via the `Foo` relation. So, I don't have a direct `DBSet<Bar>`.

My goal is to query for a `Foo`, using the `DBSet<Foo>`, that is the parent of a `Bar`. In other words, given a `BarId` of `1`, I want to get the `Foo` for that `Bar`.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
int barId = 1;

var query = from f in context.Foos
            where f.Bars.Any(b => b.BarId == barId)
            select f;

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: +1 for not joining onto Bars with an inner `from b in f.Bars` followed by a `.Distinct()`

Comment: Cool, that does it. Thanks!